# CoroutineWorker crashing when using WorkManager#enqueueUniqueWork but not when using WorkManager#enqueue

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm using Android Jetpacks's [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/). I defined a fairly standard `CoroutineWorker` doing network and DB processing but I can't uniquely enqueue it using `WorkManager#enqueueUniqueWork`.

I always end up with a

```
Work [ id=****, tags={ **** } ] was cancelled
```

But if I use `WorkManager#enqueue`, the very same work request runs perfectly.

I'm a bit clueless here. I tried to search for a similar problem elsewhere but my DDG-fu has failed me. I fear that this is tied to a coroutine problem but I'm not confortable enough with them to know where to search...

Comment: What `ExistingWorkPolicy` are you using when you call `enqueueUniqueWork`?

Comment: It's `ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. As per the [`ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE` Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy#REPLACE):

> If there is existing pending (uncompleted) work with the same unique name, **cancel** and delete it. Then, insert the newly-specified work.

Therefore it is expected that any work that uses that same unique name will be cancelled. This is true for any type of work - a `Worker` will get a callback to [`onStopped()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#onStopped()) which is the sign that it needs to cooperatively cancel itself.

Coroutines support cancellation by default, so your `CoroutineWorker` handles cancellation automatically.

Comment: Ok, but... Why the job that I just enqued wil *cancel itself after being enqued*? That's my problem. I would expect any previously enqueued work request to get cancel, but why the on that I'd like to enqueue to replace them would get canceled?

Comment: The newly enqueued work isn't cancelled, you can confirm by looking at the `getId()` of the work you're passing to `enqueueUniqueWork()` and comparing that with the logging. You may also find it helpful to [enable debug logging in WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging) if you want more information on what is happening.

Comment: Do you mean actually [testing workers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing-worker-impl) or just running your app? You haven't included any code in your question on when/where you're calling `enqueueUniqueWork`, nor have you confirmed that the IDs match. Do they match?

Comment: Ok, you are right, indeed. I had two job running one after the other. I had done a check before to make sure another job wasn't already running but the code wasn't good. Sorry about for the noise. I must be tired. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: **Edit** :Ok, a few more precisions. Multiple causes where clashing: 

- first, the non working code to check that a work request was not already ongoing,
- second: finishing an activity seems to cancel the work requests it enqued. 

Do you know if there's a way to persist a request throughout the finishing of an activity (for instance, a splash screen?)

Comment: WorkManager isn't tied to any UI at all, it runs independently of any activities you have.